# How to set calendar at global level in SSRS report (RDL file)

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, localization, rdl, gregorian-calendar

I have set the language in each textbox and also set the calendar as Default

You can see in the below image of Textbox properties

[image: Textbox properties]

Now I want to set [Gregorian] calendar in the case of [th-TH] language

I have multiple reports and each report have multiple textboxes

**How can I set this at the global level?**

Please help me out !!